# Symfony raw Sql

Tags: sql, symfony

This is my first question. I am new on symfony i just want get different products and i need their biggest category_id

```
SELECT p.title,p.price,s.*,p.image,category_id FROM shopcart s,product p JOIN product_category ON product_id=id WHERE s.productid=p.id AND userid=4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtHVv.png)

my sql is here but i want this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOP3l.png)

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a threshold on your productid like this: `WHERE productid > x` where x is your threshold. After that, you can order your row by your productid by the biggest like this: `ORDER BY productid DESC`.

After the modification I suggested, your request should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.title,
    p.price,
    s.*,
    p.image,
    category_id 
FROM 
    shopcart s,
    product p 
JOIN product_category ON product_id=id 
WHERE s.productid=p.id AND userid=4 AND s.productid > 1
ORDER BY s.productid DESC
```

PS: next time you should indicate what database storage your are using such as `mariadb`, `mysql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `postgresql` based on this post: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: They are not the same data. This data is product with multiple categories,i am using mysql. Thanks for help

Comment: If it's not the same data, you can omit the distinct. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @MuharremSarıgöl Is it about how to do "raw SQL queries" from symfony (entityManger, entities, results, PDO, param-binds) or more about - how do I write an SQL query to get what I want?